ReportLab's Text and Canvas objects not aligned although using the same left margin
I would like to have the same left adjustment for my text and some objects that I will have on my canvas.
This is the code I am using:
def on_first_dummy_page(canvas, doc):

     canvas.saveState()

     lM = A4[0] / 20  # Left Margin
     bM = A4[1] / 20  # Bottom Margin

     dW = 18*A4[0]/20 # Page Width
     dH = 18*A4[1]/20 # Page Height

     canvas.setFillColorRGB(225/255, 225/255, 225/255)
     canvas.rect(lM, bM + 18 * dH / 20, dW, dH / 20, stroke=0, fill=1)

     canvas.restoreState()

if __name__ == "__main__":

     lM = A4[0] / 20  # Left
     rM = A4[0] / 20  # Right
     bM = A4[1] / 20  # Bottom
     tM = A4[1] / 20  # Top

     dummy_doc = BaseDocTemplate(
     filename="dummy_doc.pdf",
     showBoundary=0,
     pagesize=portrait(A4),
     leftMargin=lM,
     bottomMargin=bM,
     rightMargin=rM,
     topMargin=tM)

     dummy_doc.addPageTemplates([
        PageTemplate(
            id="classic",
            frames=[Frame(A4[0] / 20, A4[1] / 20, 18*A4[0]/20, 18*A4[1]/20)],
            onPage=on_first_dummy_page)])

     dummy_page = []
     dummy_page.append(Paragraph("Mock Report", ParagraphStyle(name="dummy", alignment=TA_LEFT)))

     dummy_doc.build(dummy_page)

The problem is that the text and the rectangle do not have the same left adjustment. This is the output and I highlighted the gap between the two (which is to be honest not that big).

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
Thanks
